# Uncommited work pending when callout in @Queuable,

Tags: apex

I am working with callout to external API as well as HttpCalloutMock in test cases.

I still have the same issue from months

```
You have uncommitted work pending, Please commit or rollback.
```

I am fully aware that DML and callout need to be separated in transactions but there is not any official workaround about this.

E.g.:

```
@isTest public static void Test_01() {
 Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock, MyMock.class);
 Account account = new Account(Name = 'a');
 insert account;
 // Do my Http callout with the JSON.serialize(account)
}
```

In this example, the account HAS to be created before sending data on the external server. I already tried to put this insertion in a separated function without success.

My conclusion is that you CANNOT update or insert before a (synchronous..) Http Callout, that seems ridiculous for me as much as the request "please commit" that is totally impossible in Apex.

As another example I have a Queueable class as this:

```
public class QueueJ extends Queueable {
  public Queue_Rec__c queueRecord {get;set;}
  public QueueJ() { this.queueRecord = new Queue_Rec__c( Name = 'a' ); insert this.queueRecord; }
  public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
    // Sensitive part
    this.queueRecord.processing__c = true;
    update this.queueRecord;
    // Will throw an error 

    HttpResponse response = MyCalloutProvider.send('GET', 'url', 'uri', '{"my":"body"}');
    this.queueRecord.Processing__c = false;
    this.queueRecord.Response__c   = response.getBody();

    update this.queueRecord; // Will not crash.
  }
  public void processing() {
    this.queueRecord.processing__c = true;
    update this.queueRecord;
  }
}
```

In this quick example, if I leave the "sensitive part" and I do

```
System.enqueueJob(new QueueJ());
```

It will crash. But if I remove the "sensitive part" and I do

```
QueueJ j = new QueueJ();
j.processing();
System.enqueueJob(j);
```

it works perfectly. How can you justify this wrong/right behaviour ? It is always coinfliping to make DML and callout in the same flow.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The key here is **transaction**.

From the docs:

> By default, callouts aren’t allowed after DML operations in the same
>   transaction because DML operations result in pending uncommitted work
>   that prevents callouts from executing.

When you do this:

```
 System.enqueueJob(new QueueJ());
```

You are initiating one transaction. The transaction is asynchronous of course but its one transaction. So you can not make a DML before making a callout in that.

Now in the next scenario, when you do this:

```
QueueJ j = new QueueJ();
j.processing();
System.enqueueJob(j);
```

You are initiating 2 different transactions.
`j.processing();` will initiate a synchronous transaction where you are doing the DML. And `System.enqueueJob(j);` is a separate asynchronous transaction for your callout. So no DML before callout in a single transaction. Point to take from here is that BECAUSE you are invoking a Queueable Job(asynchronous), its treating it as different transaction, if you would have done this:

```
QueueJ j = new QueueJ();
j.processing();
j.methodToCalloutOnly();
```

Consider `methodToCalloutOnly` as a similar method to `processing` but with a callout only, no dml.

This whole thing is now a single transaction, because you took out the asynchronous aspect of it. Its a synchronous single transaction.

So if you have to a dml before making a callout, do it in a separate transaction.

**In your test class:**

```
Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock, MyMock.class);
 Account account = new Account(Name = 'a');
 insert account;
 // Do my Http callout with the JSON.serialize(account)
```

I assume the account you are inserting is your test data. So you need to keep the record creation outside your test scope, i.e Test.startTest() and Test.stopTest();

```
 Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock, MyMock.class);
 Account account = new Account(Name = 'a');
 insert account;
 Test.startTest();
 // Do my Http callout with the JSON.serialize(account)
 Test.stopTest();
```

These `startTest` and `stopTest` methods tells your test class to execute the code inside it as separate transaction with separate governor limits.

**UPDATE:**

To resolve your issue you need Queueable Job chaining.

Write one more queueable job which will do the callout ONLY,

```
public class QueueForCallout extends Queueable {
  public QueueForCallout(Id qrId) {}
  public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
    queueRecord = [Select Id from QR__c where Id = :qrId];
    HttpResponse response = MyCalloutProvider.send('GET', 'url', 'uri', '{"my":"body"}');
    this.queueRecord.Processing__c = false;
    this.queueRecord.Response__c   = response.getBody();
  }
}
```

Call this queueable job from your existing queueable job like this:

```
public class QueueJ extends Queueable {
  public Queue_Rec__c queueRecord {get;set;}
  public QueueJ() { this.queueRecord = new Queue_Rec__c( Name = 'a' ); insert this.queueRecord; }
  public void execute(QueueableContext context) {

    this.queueRecord.processing__c = true;
    update this.queueRecord;

    System.enqueueJob(new QueueForCallout(queueRecord.Id)); //This will initiate a separate asynchronous transaction.
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation, it helps (especially the last part about Test.startTest() that creates a new transaction).

Btw it is still not working with the same issue:
http://paste.awesom.eu/OOfS

Comment: I assume you are doing a DML before callout inside the execute method of QueueIt. That's a single transaction. You can chain queueable jobs one after another, in the first one, do the DML and in the next one do the callout. This will initiate 2 separate asynchronous transactions.

Comment: I am not following anymore. Does it mean that if I want to test the execute method, I need to wrap the call of this queueable in an other queueable written only for test purpose ? It does not seem logic to make it that complicated. Regarding your (logical) explanation of the transaction, I am disturbed that the Test.startTest() & Test.stopTest() do not resolve my entire issue..

Comment: And to add one layer of non sense (my pov) about:
  QueueJ j = new QueueJ();
  j.processing();
  System.enqueueJob(j);

I first added a function on QueueJ that enqueue itself (System.enqueueJob(this);)
So I was able to do "new QueueJ().processing().enqueue();" but it resulted on the SAME uncommited transaction issue.

Comment: Updated my answer with how you can solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot make DML and callout in same transaction.

Salesforce has designed this such a way that before sending data to external system the data must be fully committed, otherwise no way we can guarantee about the completeness of transaction. Data will not be in memory before callout.
This basically conforms the guarantee of the data in SFDC and external system can rely on Salesforce about the data before reaching to them.

2nd thing, Salesforce do not want to control about the transaction management both in SFDC and external system, that's why it expects to the performed the callout asynchronously.

Not only the code you have shared about the transaction, we cannot even update record and send and workflow email alert in a same transaction.

You could get workarounds [Error:You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out..](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000079772&language=en_US&type=1)

It is advisable to wrap asynchronous process related testing between `Test.startTest();` and `Test.stopTest();` and put the assert statement after `Test.stopTest();`

> All asynchronous calls made after the startTest method are collected by the system. When stopTest is executed, all asynchronous processes are run synchronously. If you don’t include the System.schedule or System.enqueueJob() method within the startTest and stopTest methods, the scheduled job executes at the end of your test method for Apex saved using Salesforce.com API.

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Santanu - check your first line, DML can be made after callouts in the same transaction, just not before. See doc: `You can’t make a callout when there are pending operations in the same transaction. Things that result in pending operations are DML statements, asynchronous Apex (such as future methods and batch Apex jobs), scheduled Apex, or sending email. You can make callouts before performing these types of operations`